# Highlight active parenthesis pair in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, racket, sicp

How can I make vs code highlight inside a pair of parenthesis when put cursor at one of the parenthesis (this is drracket editor)
[image]

Comment: VSC already shows the matching bracket and with bracket colorizer you get a colored line between the brackets

Comment: [Don't use `#lang scheme`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scheme/index.html), btw

Comment: Might also want to read through [the style guide on code formatting](https://docs.racket-lang.org/style/Textual_Matters.html)